# How can I view all the NXT nodes that I can access publiclly?

Tags: nxt

Where can i find a list of NXT IP nodes that I can connect to publicly? I want to be able to use them as a backup connection to the nxt blockchain if my own nxt server crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.peerexplorer.com/api for a list of active peers including their public API status